# How to tell VS Code format doc to wrap line after certain length?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to format HTML document, VS Code would wrap a line that is too long into multiple lines.

I think VS Code let the line grow too long before wrapping. Is there a setting in VS Code to tell it to wrap after certain line length?

This question is NOT a duplicate of the [hard wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122175/196451) question. This is about wrapping during format document process.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open user settings: File - Preferences - Settings

Then add/edit this item:

```
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 80
```

FYI the new settings are in effect after you save the changes.

Comment: Is there any way to do this if it isn't an HTML file?

Comment: for me this didn't work.

Comment: To anyone finding that this may not be working do check that there isn't a custom .vscode/settings.json file in your workspace that is overriding the html.format.wrapLineLength setting

Answer (score 13):

If you are formatting HTML and are annoyed that VScode formats your long lines into multiple lines, go to:

```
File > Preferences > Settings
```

Search for:

```
HTML › Format: Wrap Line Length
```

and set it to `0`

Comment: for me this didn't work.

Comment: To anyone finding that this may not be working do check that there isn't a custom .vscode/settings.json file in your workspace that is overriding the html.format.wrapLineLength setting

Comment: Also check for `editor.rulers` and `prettier.printWidth`