# VScode: word wrap for markdown not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to have an automatic word wrap when I write markdown text: I expect that lines are automatically broken when I type a line longer than the `wrap line length` set, by a hard 
break (i.e. a `newline` character).

I have set

- `word wrap` to `wordWrapColumn`
- `word wrap column` to 50
- `wrappingIndent` to same
- `wrapping Strategy` to simple
- `wrap attributes` to auto 
  and nothing set to markdown.

Nevertheless, lines extend to the end of the editor (much more than 50) and nothing happens. I have tried the `toggle word wrap` with no effect (it would be great if the state of the toggle would be shown, like for `auto save`).

What is wrong?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 36):

VSCode automatically sets some Markdown-specific settings behind the scenes that override general user settings, which is why the "editor.wordWrap" setting is seemingly ignored.

To get around this, you can add the setting as language-specific for markdown files.

i.e. try adding the following to your settings.json file and it should work!

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80
}
```

NOTE: There is an open [feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74195)  to make it more obvious when language settings override user defaults. At least they are aware of the issue!

Comment: It looks like that feature was merged: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131707

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, as OP asked for hard wrapping, i.e. inserting a newline character. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839079/7232335) addresses that.

Comment: May be quite obvious for some people but I just realized that `markdown` is not the same as `mdx`, hence that one could also be necessary if you want to apply that to `.mdx` files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277363/8816585