# How to see preview of .mdx file as markdown in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Is there a way I can *force* VSCode to preview `*.mdx` files as markdown just like it does for `*.md` files? For reference see how Github shows preview of [this](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Personal-Site-Gourav.io/blob/master/pages/blog/setup-vscode-to-run-debug-c-cpp-code/index.mdx) mdx file

I know there's an extension [MDX Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyc.vscode-mdx-preview) but that's not working for `next.js` project. see [open issue](https://github.com/xyc/vscode-mdx-preview/issues/41).

I tried this vscode setting but doesn't work:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.mdx": "md"
  },
```

Comment: `"*.mdx": "markdown"`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In `files.associations` you mention the languageId to use for a particular file extension

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.mdx": "markdown"
},
```