# Vscode: spanning System.out.print() over multiple lines

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Eclipse has a feature that makes it easy to separate a long message inside System.out.print. For example, when pressing enter inside the quotes in the following:

```
System.out.print("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
```

Eclipse automatically splits it to:

```
System.out.print("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
           + " consectetur adipiscing elit,"
           + " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"
           + " ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
```

Is there a way to imitate this behaviour in Vscode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically hard wrap lines at column in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122175/automatically-hard-wrap-lines-at-column-in-vscode)

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari
Partially. The solutions that I saw in the discussions were mainly about comments. In my case, I need to enter additional characters ( {"} then {Enter} then {+} then {"} ) At the same time have them indented to the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work around that I found. (Not the best solution)

`CTRL + SHIFT + P` > Configure user snippets > java.json,

Type the following snippet:

```
  "Java newline": {
"prefix": "nn",
"body": [
  "\"",
  "+ \""
],
"description": "Automatically inserts quotations and plus"}
```

When the cursor is inside 2 quotations, you can type `nn` then `tab` to get the desired result.